# Recording Keyboard Output Using Audacity

Tags: keyboard, midi, setup, audacity

I'm trying setup my Casio CTK-6000 electric keyboard to be able to be recorded through my Windows 10 computer using Audacity. I have [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0100FSSE4) USB cable and I have connected the keyboard to the computer. In the device manager I see that Windows recognizes it as "CASIO USB-MIDI [0]" and "CASIO USB-MIDI [1]" (not sure why there are two entries) under "Software devices".

I turn on the keyboard, open Audacity and go to Edit -> Preferences -> Devices. The option for the keyboard is nowhere in any of the dropdown menus. How do I get this setup to work?

Comment: "Not sure why there are two entries" - this is irrelevant to solving the OP's problem, but the reason is that *real* MIDI cables only transmit data in one direction. A USB cable can transmit data in either direction. One of the two *virtual* USB-MIDI devices is for receiving MIDI data from the Casio, the other one is for sending MIDI data from the computer to the Casio.

Answer (score 4):

According to the manual http://support.casio.com/storage/en/manual/pdf/EN/008/CTK6000_WK6500_EN.pdf the USB port on the keyboard is for MIDI data only. That is consistent with Windows recognizing it as a MIDI port.

The MIDI data transmits commands that say when notes start and end, but it doesn't transmit the audio that you want to record with Audacity.

You need to connect the LINE OUT jacks on the Casio to an audio input on the computer. Your sound card will probably have LINE IN socket (colored light blue on a standard Windows PC). From the manual, you probably need a cable with two mono plugs at the Casio end and one stereo plug at the computer end. Don't use the Microphone In socket (pink) on the computer - the output level from the Casio will be too high.

Note, in principle it is possible to transmit audio data over a USB cable, but the Casio doesn't support that directly. If you really want to do it that way, you will need to buy a USB audio interface plus the right audio cable(s) to connect it to the Casio. There is no obvious advantage in doing it that way, and it will be more expensive.

Comment: Worth noting that transmitted MIDI data is often used to control the sound of a VST synthesizer, so you can use your Midi enables Casio keyboard to control a variety of sounds by enabling the plugin on the track in question.

Comment: Alright, does [this](https://www.amazon.com/HENGSHENG%C2%AE-3-5mm-Stereo-6-35mm-Splitter/dp/B01BTSUFWY/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1467376509&sr=8-1&keywords=two+mono+to+stereo) item seem like it would be the right choice (two mono to a stereo)?

Comment: That cable will probably do the trick, but you need to ask two questions: 1) does the Casio have a stereo output with two jack sockets? 2) Does your PC soundboard mini jack microphone input is stereo? If not you'll probably be better off with a similar, but mono, cable.

Comment: Kyle's comment is quite right in the general case, but Audacity is a purely audio application, it does not support MIDI. A possible way to make it work would be to use an external MIDI host like [vsthost](http://www.hermannseib.com/english/vsthost.htm) and then record in Audacity from the "what you hear" or equivalent audio source.

Comment: @joseem I will check what the input/outputs are like for my keyboard and PC when I get the chance, thanks. However, are you saying here that I can record with MIDI by using vsthost? Would there be any difference between this MIDI recording and the recording that would be achieved using stereo/mono method?

Comment: If you want to record the sound produced by your Casio, you need to record audio. The comments about vsthost only apply if you want to use your Casio keyboard to "play" some *other* sounds that are generated by your computer (and your original question did not seem to be about that situation).

Comment: "Alright, does this item seem like it would be the right choice" Yes, that is the right general type of cable, but check that the sockets on your Casio are *the same type and size* to match the red and white plugs on the cable.  I don't know if I was reading *exactly* the right manual for your keyboard, so I can't definitely answer yes or no.

Comment: @alephzero Alright, I have the cable plugged into the keyboard and my computer and everything seems to fit fine. Audacity still doesn't give any extra options to switch devices. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You need one of these and you need one of these cables because audacity cannot record midi. https://www.adorama.com/beuca202.html?utm_source=adl-gbase

https://www.zzounds.com/item--HOSTRS?siid=110444&gclid=CjwKCAjwwYP2BRBGEiwAkoBpAmdvmbab4d8v2FZPXP6SQZ_JrWxnLKeH9iD7sqFhLrTmh4OIsiPWoxoClzUQAvD_BwE